# How to change php for navigation Magento? Recursive method

Tags: magento-1.9, php, layered-navigation

I need to get a sub-category for category ID 3. Recursive method. How to do it correctly? I have this code.

```
<div class="multi-accordion">
<?php
$rootcatId= Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($rootcatId);
function  get_categories($categories) {
  $array= '<ul>';
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
        $count = $cat->getProductCount();
        $array .= '<li>'.
        '<a href="' . Mage::getUrl($cat->getUrlPath()). '">' .
                  $category->getName() . "(".$count.")</a>\n";
        if($category->hasChildren()) {
            $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($category->getId());
             $array .=  get_categories($children);
            }
         $array .= '</li>';
    }
    return  $array . '</ul>';
}
echo  get_categories($categories); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out the following approach:

```
$parent = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
$tree = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_tree');
$nodes = $tree->loadNode($parent)
  ->loadChildren($recursionLevel)
  ->getChildren();
$tree->addCollectionData(null, false, $parent, true, false);
// Now, you can use $nodes as category tree
foreach($nodes as $category){
  // Do something
}
```

Be aware that `category_tree` object is different from `category` and is mostly used for rendering naviation menu.
Your current solution has a `load` call inside a recursion function. That is a performance killing combination.
Update:
so, to get all children categories for `category_id = 3` and recursion level `2` you should do following:
    `$tree = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_tree');
    $nodes = $tree->loadNode(3)
      ->loadChildren(2)
      ->getChildren();`

Comment: Sergey, nope you can insert category 3 instead of `$parrent`

Comment: Please tell me where?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But to be honest, it did not help me. I do not know what to do with it. I have a multi-level menu. https://jsfiddle.net/Sylon/vej9hckh/1/

Comment: There are three levels in the menu.

Comment: then do `loadChildren(3)`

Comment: You will understand only professional. And I still have a <ul> and <if>